# How to implement this layout in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, layout

I'm pretty new in Flex development. Now I'm learning layouts in Flex. I try to make the following layout.
[alt text http://get2know.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/2010-04-23_232857.png](http://get2know.it/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/2010-04-23_232857.png)
The red arrow means when enlarge the window, the red arrow widget will become large too. Can anyone implement this layout in Flex? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes Yousui good luck:

```
<s:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout/>
</s:layout>
<s:Label text="Name:" left="9.8" top="16.4" width="38" height="12"/>
<s:Label text="Description:" left="9.75" top="45.85"/>
<s:Label text="Pattern:" left="9.5" top="76"/>
<s:TextInput left="85" top="10" right="353"/>
<s:TextInput left="85.5" top="40" right="10.5"/>
<s:TextArea left="86" top="70" right="7" bottom="34"/>
<s:Button label="Insert Variable" bottom="6" left="86"/>
<s:Label text="Context:" width="45" top="16" right="300"/>
<s:ComboBox width="150" top="10" right="143"/>
<s:CheckBox label="Automatically insert" top="11" right="10.700012"/>
<s:Button label="Cancel" right="7" bottom="6.450012"/>
<s:Button label="OK" right="84.599976" bottom="6.799988"/>
```

If you are using Flash Builder Mac or Win version you have the Design view available *(Linux Flash Builder doesn't have)*, this design would be easy to do.

But i guess that you probably aren't used to the way that Flash Builder handles control positioning, if thats the case:

- Paste this code in the MXML file you have
- Go to Design view and select one of these controls.
- You will see in the Properties Panel in the Size and Position section, a sub section named Constrains, there is were you can lock (right, left, top and bottom) the corners of your control in a way that you would get the desired effect that you needed.

Case your Properties panel isn't visible. Go to Window > Show View > Properties.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

If you have the `MinWidth` and `MinHeight` properties specified in your Application tag, beware that when shrinking your Flash App, the layout will adjust your layout to a minimum specified in those properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<VBox>
    <HBox>
        ... // Name, context...
    </HBox>
    <HBox>
        ... // Description...
    </HBox>
    <HBox>
        <Label text="Pattern: "/>
        <VBox>
             ... // text and insert variable
        </VBox>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

For your scaling, just set your expanding controls to have width and/or heights of "100%" in the MXML.